# Docker ports mapping in the .yml file has not changed the container port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

consider a docker .yml file  like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=prisma_pg
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=benchmark
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5454:5432'
volumes:
  postgres:
```

after I ran these commands:

`docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml up -d`

`docker-compose ps`

its State is UP and the `ports` column showing
`0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`
illustrates that the running port is not set to `5454->5432` as we described in the yaml file, 
How can we fix it to map the port correctly?

**Edit:**
the file is saved in the same directory and there is no other container running before or after this one:

here is the screenshot, which probably helps:
[image]

Comment: If you described `ports` as `5454:5432` and you see `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`, then you must've done something wrong. Run `docker compose down -v` and run `docker compose up -d` again. Make sure you've saved the *compose* file before running the *up` command.

Comment: that is just impossible , maybe you are using another yaml file or another container status! i used your docker-compose and its fine

Comment: As other have mentioned, you are talking about a docker.yaml file, but your command references a docker-compose.yaml file. Retrace your steps and ensure your files are as expected.

Comment: i added the screenshot, which probably helps @msrumon

Comment: It simply CANNOT happen! `docker compose` command will automatically pick up *docker-compose* or *compose* files by default (not sure which one gets the preference), so you don't have to mention that `-f` flag for your case. Can you share a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: Which version are you using with `docker compose version` or `docker-compose --version`? Currently, I have docker compose v2.22.0. So, with this version port mapping works as expected.

Comment: @msrumon It works on `labs.play-with-docker.com`! the config is correct and still sucks on my machine!

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad the previous version was 22 and I  removed docker entirely, installed the latest (  24.0.6 ) does not  make any change

Comment: 1) Uninstall Docker Desktop. 2) Restart the PC. 3) Install Docker Desktop.
See if that helps. Otherwise, it's basically a blind-game at this point. 'Cause you and everyone else know that the config is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the docker file out of project space and it WORKED!

the problem was aroused from a merge that had made a similarly named directory in the project. so the port changes had been applied to the other one.
So the container and docker are OK( I appreciated all the people's efforts, especially @msrumon
who helped me in this important part to forget about the config and seek another reason)

Answer (score 0):

Try running with Compose V2 by omitting the hyphen:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml
```

Do you get the same result?

Comment: yes, same result with `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up`

Comment: Could you try using double quotes instead of single quotes for the ports? Although not related to this specifically, Docker suggests to use double quotes due to it parsing ports in base 60.